How can I use triggers if joining tables is involved? SQL
All of my code executes and my tables properly populate. The only problem is with my procedure. When I call it it says "column 'store_id' does not exist. Looking for help.
-- Define tables 
CREATE TABLE detailed_rental_report (
    rental_id INT,
    rental_date DATE,
    film_title VARCHAR(255),
    payment_amount DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE summary_rental_report(    
    store_id INT,    
    total_rentals INT,  
    total_revenue DECIMAL(10,2)    
);    

-- Trigger to ensure summary report is updated when new information is inserted
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary_rental_report() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$ 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO summary_rental_report (store_id, total_rentals, total_revenue)
    VALUES (NEW.store_id,
            (SELECT COUNT(rental_id) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date),
            (SELECT SUM(payment_amount) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date))
    ON CONFLICT (store_id) DO UPDATE
    SET total_rentals = (SELECT COUNT(rental_id) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date),
        total_revenue = (SELECT SUM(payment_amount) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_summary_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON detailed_rental_report
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_summary_rental_report();  

-- Stored procedure to refresh data in both detailed and summary tables
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE refresh_rental_report() AS
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM detailed_rental_report;
    DELETE FROM summary_rental_report;
    INSERT INTO detailed_rental_report (rental_id, rental_date, film_title, payment_amount)
    SELECT
        rental.rental_id,
        rental.rental_date,
        film.title AS film_title,
        payment.amount AS payment_amount
    FROM rental
    JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
    JOIN film ON inventory.film_id = film.film_id
    JOIN payment ON rental.rental_id = payment.rental_id;
    
    INSERT INTO summary_rental_report (store_id, total_rentals, total_revenue)
    SELECT
        store.store_id,
        COUNT(rental.rental_id) AS total_rentals,
        SUM(payment.amount) AS total_revenue
    FROM rental
    JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id
    JOIN store ON inventory.store_id = store.store_id
    JOIN payment ON rental.rental_id = payment.rental_id
    GROUP BY store.store_id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Call the procedure to refresh data
CALL refresh_rental_report();  


Deleting the update_summary_trigger allows me to call the procedure but then my summary_rental_report table will not update.

put a try catch in it and dump to log table and also it should say column doesn't exist in [TABLE NAME]

Where should NEW.store_id come from? It’s not in the table that fires the trigger

As @Frank Heikens pointed out in the comment, there is no store_id in detailed_rental_report.
Try this one:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary_rental_report() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$ 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO summary_rental_report (store_id, total_rentals, total_revenue)
    VALUES ((SELECT inventory.store_id FROM rental JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id = inventory.inventory_id WHERE rental.rental_id = NEW.rental_id),
            (SELECT COUNT(rental_id) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date),
            (SELECT SUM(payment_amount) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date))
    ON CONFLICT (store_id) DO UPDATE
    SET total_rentals = (SELECT COUNT(rental_id) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date),
        total_revenue = (SELECT SUM(payment_amount) FROM detailed_rental_report WHERE rental_date = NEW.rental_date);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

However, you have a more fundamental problem. refresh_rental_report will trigger update_summary_rental_report for each row. You'd better rewrite update_summary_rental_report to update all rows at once. And trigger probably is not required either, all inserts could be done from refresh_rental_report.
